# Android Firebase - User Registration with Profile Photo

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-authentication, registration

I have been looking through the Firebase documentation, as well as searches on stackoverflow, google, and YouTube for the following:

Creating a user registration that allows for email, password, and profile photo.

I am able to successfully add a user with their email and password but I can't seem to get the other information in(most importantly the profile photo). All the tutorials and documentation show how someone who is ALREADY a (logged in) User can upload a photo to firebase, but not for someone that's registering. Can someone help out here, how can I get the profile photo and first/lastname uploaded with the new users?

I am using FirebaseAuth to add the users.

This is what I have so far:

```
checkmarkImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailET.getText().toString(), passwordET.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                          //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                              Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                          }
                                          }
                                  });
                      }
                  });

        uploadProfilePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                handleChooseImage(view);
            }
        });


    }

    //END OF onCreate

    //Separate methods

    //Actually opens the CameraRoll
        public void handleChooseImage(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);  //then goes to onActivityResult
        }
        public void handleInsertData(View v) {

        }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if(requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i("RegisterActivity", "case 0");
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    Log.i("RegisterActivity", "selected image = " + selectedImage);

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to signup first and then upload user image in storage this is standard way.

because as per firebase storage default rule `user != null` so must user auth state not null or else you can change firebase rule into public (it's not preferable)

i hope this will help you.

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(SignupActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                     if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    aDialog.show();
                                } else {
                                    final String uid = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();

                                    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("user_profile").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
                                    filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                                            if (progress == 100) {
                                                hideProgressDialog();
                                                //upload();
                                            }
                                            System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
                                        }
                                    }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            System.out.println("Upload is paused");
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                        }
                                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            /** Get Image Download Path**/
                                            Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                                            /** Converting Image Uri In String **/

                                            if (downloadUri != null) {
                                                imagerls = downloadUri.toString();
                                            }

                                            //Add user data and image URL to firebase database
                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: To clarify, you are saying you cannot upload an image while you are Registering a new account? Only after the user is already in the database and goes to update? If so, what is your above code doing? Thanks

Comment: Of course, you can upload your image white user registering, but standard way is first you complete your registration and then inside your -onSuccessListner- upload image, Ones done image uploading get image URL, and store user data with newly uploaded image URL , my code did same task for me.

Comment: I suggest let the user login first, by that you'll get that user object and then upload image to firebase storage with that user Id( to have unique link for user profile images from firebase storage)make update on the user object. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload image regardless of the registration of the user on the firebase,
however, you would need the user reference to save the image to get it again when the user signs in, and you can't have that user's reference if the user is not already registered. 
makes sense? :)

Comment: Does this mean it needs to be done on a separate activity / Java file ? I think so, although why can a username&password be associated with what at the moment of registering doesn't have a reference?

Comment: 1: you can upload image on registration success listener against the email id in the same activity, OR
2: you can register and login and use FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() to get the current user for ref and save the image in the main activity, this is what i'd suggest.
save email, pass and the path to user's display in the database as well, of course.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late, but for anyone else coming here for a reliable answer, I'll show you how I achieved exactly that.

I have a POJO class CreatedUserDetail, with email and photo fields.

I also created a User class:

```
public class User{
private String uid;
private String password;
private String email;
private String photo;

public User( String email, String photo, String password ){
    this.email = email;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.password = password;
}

public void saveToFirebase(){
    CreatedUserDetail userDetail = new CreatedUserDetail();
    userDetail.setEmail( email );
    userDetail.setImage( photo );

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child( "Users" )
            .child( uid ).setValue( userDetail );
}

private void uploadProfileImage(){
    final StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child( "pics" +
                    uid +
                    photo.substring( photo.lastIndexOf( "." ) ) );

    UploadTask uploadTask = mStorageReference.putFile( Uri.fromFile( new File( photo ) ) );
    uploadTask.continueWithTask( new Continuation< UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task< Uri > >(){
        @Override
        public Task< Uri > then( @NonNull Task< UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > task ) throws Exception{
            if( !task.isSuccessful() )
                throw task.getException();

            return mStorageReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        } ).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener< Uri >(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete( @NonNull Task< Uri > task ){
            if( task.isSuccessful() ){
                photo = task.getResult().toString();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference( "Users" )
                        .child( uid )
                        .child( "image" )
                        .setValue( photo );
            }
        }
    } );
}

public void RegisterUser( final OnUserRegistrationCallback onUserRegistrationCallback ){
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email, password )
            .addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener< AuthResult >(){
                @Override
                public void onSuccess( AuthResult authResult ){
                    uid = authResult.getUser().getUid();
                    saveToFirebase();
                    uploadProfileImage();
                }
            } )
            .addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener(){
                @Override
                public void onFailure( @NonNull Exception e ){
                }
            } );
}
```

}

As you can see, it has a RegisterUser function, which first creates a user in Firebase  Authentication with given email and password.  Once it has been registered, I create a user in Firebase Database with email and LOCAL PATH to photo. Meanwhile, it also uploads the photo to Firebase Storage.  And finally, on completion of the upload, I update the Firebase Database node with the downloadUrl of the recently uploaded photograph.

And in the activity, I just do this:

```
    mUserWithEmailAndPassword = new User( mEmailToVerify, mLocalPath, mPass );
    mUserWithEmailAndPassword.RegisterUser();
```

And that's all.  You can include a callback to show a Toast or a redirect to another activity.